# How to Start with NodeJS Web Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling

I am a  Java/JavaScript developer and now want to move to NodeJS for developing the web apps. I have been through several tutorials but am really confused on how to start with the development. I dint find any end to end application where each aspect of the Node is mentioned such as the Model View and the Controller.Since I am not able to start just due to the lack of sample program and a correct path to follow. I also have another question that whether is it possible to make a desktop applications using Node. Please point me to appropriate tutorials which show end to end development pattern as well as all other necessary resource so as to start development with Node easier.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading about node.js. A good free book to get started is [Mixu's Node.js book](http://book.mixu.net/). Focus on basics Chapters 1 to 8.

Beyond the JavaScript basics you need to understand the Node.js event model, one of the things you may run into when starting out is the callback hell, so pay attentions to chapter 7 in this book.

Chapter 8 in this book will talk about install npm packages and package.json. This stuff is important and will come handy if you want to do work with node packages, or package your node.js app for deployment.

Once you have basics covered you can look into developing web app using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework. For unit testing you can use [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) framework

I love to experiment by writing unit tests  so during the learning phase start by writing simple unit tests that test node.js API.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ExpressJs](http://expressjs.com/)

API and some tutorials are on site.

If you want to jump into coding immediately look at [code examples on github](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples), they cover all essential parts of webapp.